# Issues settings up drush + phpunit

Tags: testing

I'm trying to set up drush + phpunit, following these two guides:

- the official [Drush/tests/README.md](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/tests/README.md)
- [Getting Started Testing Drush Commands](https://codedrop.com.au/blog/getting-started-testing-drush-commands) which is the most recent guide I could find

Here's what I have so far:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.2
- PHPUnit 5.7.5 at `/users/wim.mostrey/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit`
- Drush 8.1.9 at `/users/wim.mostrey/.composer/vendor/bin/drush`
- Drush tests at `/users/wim.mostrey/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/tests`
- a simple test `migrateManifestTest` at `/users/wim.mostrey/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/tests/migrateManifestTest.php`

I try to run the test using the following command:

```
UNISH_NO_TIMEOUTS=1 UNISH_DRUPAL_MAJOR_VERSION=8 ./unish.sh --filter=migrateManifestTest
```

However I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Unish\UnitUnishTestCase' not found in /Users/wim.mostrey/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/tests/bootstrap.inc on line 51
```

I tried searching online for this error but got no results at all. I tried running both `unish.sh` and `phpunit` from different locations and using different configuration options, to no avail.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so here's what I did, with help from MegaChriz.

The dev dependencies for Drush need to be installed and the phpunit version that comes with Drush should be used instead of a 'general' phpunit. So not the one I installed through composer.

1. Git clone of Drush from my home folder (`/users/wim.mostrey`)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git
   cd drush
   git checkout 8.1.9
   ```
2. Install Drush with dev dependencies using Composer while being inside the Drush folder

   ```
   composer install
   ```
3. Execute built-in tests pointing to the phpunit version from Drush:

   ```
   UNISH_NO_TIMEOUTS=1 /users/wim.mostrey/drush/vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration /users/wim.mostrey/drush/tests --filter=ImageCase
   ```

   or for Drupal 7 tests:

   ```
   UNISH_NO_TIMEOUTS=1 UNISH_DRUPAL_MAJOR_VERSION=7 /users/wim.mostrey/drush/vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration /users/wim.mostrey/drush/tests /users/wim.mostrey/Sites/drupal7/sites/all/modules/feeds/tests/drush
   ```

[image: Great success]